# How to access IP Geo location services in sitecore 9.3 when Tracking is disabled

Tags: pipelines

How to access IP Geolocation services in Sitecore XP version 9.3, as we are going to disable Analytics tracker in a custom processor (Cookie Consent) which is called before CreateTracker processor of the StartAnalytics Pipeline.

In the below link it has mentioned that when the Tracker is disabled,IP Geolocation services are unavailable.
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/enable-disable-the-xdb-and-the-tracker.html

As IP Geolocation services are strongly related to the xDB, Analytics and Tracking,I would like to know how to use IP Geolocation services when Tracking is disabled